# LISTEN/NOTIFY pgconnection goes down java?

Tags: postgresql, java, jdbc

I am using PostgreSQL DB and applying it's `LISTEN/NOTIFY` functionality. So my listener is at my AS (Application Server) and I have triggers configured on my DB such that when CRUD operations are performed on a table a `NOTIFY` request is sent on AS.

**LISTENER** class in java:

```
    @Singleton
    @Startup
NotificationListenerInterface.class)
    public class NotificationListener extends Thread implements NotificationListenerInterface {

        @Resource(mappedName="java:/RESOURCES") 
        private DataSource ds;

        @PersistenceContext(unitName = "one")
        EntityManager em;

        Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(NotificationListener.class);

        private Connection Conn;
        private PGConnection pgConnection = null;
        private NotifyRequest notifyRequest = null;

        @PostConstruct
        public void notificationListener() throws Throwable {

            System.out.println("Notification****************");
            try
            {


                Class.forName("com.impossibl.postgres.jdbc.PGDriver");
                String url = "jdbc:pgsql://192.xx.xx.126:5432/postgres";


                Conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"postgres","password");
                this.pgConnection = (PGConnection) Conn;

                System.out.println("PG CONNECTON: "+ pgConnection);
                Statement listenStatement = Conn.createStatement();
                listenStatement.execute("LISTEN notify_channel");
                listenStatement.close();

                pgConnection.addNotificationListener(new PGNotificationListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void notification(int processId, String channelName, String payload){

                        System.out.println("*********INSIDE NOTIFICATION*************");

                        System.out.println("Payload: " + jsonPayload);
```

}

So as my AS is up, I have configured that at startup the listener class is called and it's start listening on the channel.

Now this works fine if like say for testing I edit my table in DB manually, the notification is generated and the LISTENER receives it.

However, when I programmatically send a UPDATE request on the table, the UPADTE is performed successfully but LISTENER is not receiving anything.

I feel my connection of the LISTENER goes down when I send a request (it also makes a connection to edit entities), but I am not sure. I read about permanent connections and pooled connections, but not able to decide how to pursue that.

I am using pgjdbc (http://impossibl.github.io/pgjdbc-ng/) jar for async notifications as jdbc connection requires polling.